# Solve $(1+\sin(x))\cdot y'=y\cdot \ln(y)\cdot \cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometric-integrals

I am given the following differential equation $$(1+\sin(x))\cdot y'=y\cdot \ln(y)\cdot \cos(x)$$ $$\left(previously \space\space(1+\sin(x))\cdot y'=y\cdot \ln(y)+ \cos(x)\right)$$
After separating variables I arrrived at $$\int\frac{dy}{y\ln(y)}=\int\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}dx\space\space\space.....(I)$$ The solution I have arrvied at is $$\ln\left|\ln(y)\right|=\ln(1+\sin(x))+k$$$$\rightarrow y=c\cdot e^{1+\sin(x)} $$$$c=\pm e^{e^{k}}$$
But I tried using a Weierstrass substitution for (I)'s rhs integral, Let $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})\rightarrow dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$ , this yields: $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
After applying the substitution in $\int\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}dx$, I arrived at $$\int\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}dx=\frac{2}{\tan(\frac{x}{2})+1}+k$$$$\rightarrow y=c\cdot e^{e^{\frac{2}{\tan(\frac{x}{2})+1}}} $$ $$c=\pm e^{e^{k}}$$
Why are the two solutions unequal ?

Comment: Quick check on Wolfram suggests that an analytical solution does not exist

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Wolfram suggested a solution that may have included using Euler's formula which I can't see any gain from using it here

Comment: Are you sure that the rhs is not $y\log(y)+y \cos(x)$ ? This was underlined by @user577215664. in comments.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I doubted that before too, now I can ask my professor to recheck the equation for typos, perhaps he could have really missed the $y$ there, I'll come back here when I get a reply :-)

Comment: In any manner, even if it is $y\log(y)+y \cos(x)$, the result would probably be a monster.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it was indeed a mistake, the equation is $$(1+\sin(x))\cdot y′=y\cdot \ln(y)\cdot \cos(x)$$ I should now change the question

Answer (score 1):

If the problem was "just"$$(1+\sin(x))\, y'=y\, \log(y)$$ it would be simple since separable
$$\int\frac {dy}{y\log(y)}=\log (\log (y))$$  You could also use
$$y=e^{e^z}\quad  \implies  \quad e^{z+e^{z}} \left((1+\sin (x)) z'-1\right)=0$$ which is separable and easy to integrate using the tangent half-angle substitution
$$z=c_1+\frac{2}{1+\cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

Just stay with an integration factor.

Comment: @user577215664. You are more than likely correct. Good point ! Using $y=e^{e^z}$ it is a small monster but doable. Cheers :-)